# How do I print a displayed form in my Winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, printing

what is the code in C# for printing a form in the application?

Answer (score 1):

Use both a PrintDialog and Printing the Current Form from C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287529(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use

[PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx)

class.

For code sample see [Printing Using C#](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Printing-Using-C-sharp/1/)